# Subaru 2007 outback with passenger heat problems

Tags: subaru, heat

My Subaru does not have auto heat, it is manual. When I turn on the heat it works fine on the drivers side and blows cold air on the passenger side.

Comment: Is this a dual zone system by design (with different temperatures set between driver and passenger?). Do you have a photo of control panel?

Comment: As there's heat on one side only, the bits in common (the heat exchanger and its plumbing) are working correctly. Something in the mechanism that controls the side-to-side distribution is broken. This could be either the side-to-side blend door itself, or whatever controls the door position; the vacuum lines/motor/control switch, or electrical lines/motor/switch, or physical control knob/lever and control cable.

Comment: Welcome, there's mix doors and blend doors behind the dash and more of them on the dual zone climate control.  As mentioned above a photo of the controls would be good.